# Multi-tenant based partitioning

Tags: sql, partitioning, multi-tenant

We do have an existing clean up service that drops time based partitions that are no longer needed that works well on a single tenant application. However, we're now supporting multi-tenants, and would need to find a way to specifically drop partitions per tenants.

Each tenant would have a different specs / requirement for the clean up service.

Eg.

```
Tenant A would only want to keep their data for 90 days, we then drop partitions older than 90 days. 

Tenant B would only want to keep their data for 30 days, we then drop partitions older than 30 days.
```

We tried doing different approaches using RANGE BY COLUMN partition type as it does seem to be the only type of partition that fits our use case.

```sql
CREATE TABLE test_table (
  id        INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
  tenantId VARCHAR(255),
  createdAt DATETIME,
  PRIMARY KEY (id, tenantId, createdAt));

ALTER TABLE test_table PARTITION BY RANGE COLUMNS (createdAt, tenantId) (
PARTITION p0_tenant_id_1 VALUES LESS THAN ('2019-07-22 00:00:00', 'tenant_id_1'),
PARTITION p0_tenant_id_2 VALUES LESS THAN ('2019-07-22 00:00:00', 'tenant_id_2'),
PARTITION p1_tenant_id_1 VALUES LESS THAN ('2019-07-23 00:00:00', 'tenant_id_1'),
PARTITION p1_tenant_id_2 VALUES LESS THAN ('2019-07-23 00:00:00', 'tenant_id_2')
);
```

The problem with the above approach is that the number of partitions would be relative to the number of tenants, and we're looking to support around tens of thousands of tenants, I'm afraid we are going to exceed the number of partitions available. Another thing is that the above approach does not allow for us have a catch all partitions using PMAX.

Has anyone tried doing a multi-tenant based table partitioning? How did you do it?

Any input / help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What dbms is this, specifically? Oracle? MSSQL? Something else?

Comment: Is it feasible for your business case to have several tenants in the same partition, so you could have e.g. `tenant_id_10*` through `tenant_id_99*` in the same partition?

Comment: @RossPresser we'll be supporting mysql, mssql and oracle. For now, we're starting w/ mysql.

Re. `Is it feasible for your business case to have several tenants in the same partition`

I don't think we could do that. Each tenant would have a different specs / requirement for the clean up service. Eg. 

Tenant A would only want to keep their data for 90 days, we then drop partitions older than 90 days.

Tenant B would only want to keep their data for 30 days, we then drop partitions older than 30 days.

Comment: You could add a schema per tenant and place those schema objects on their own partition. Example: `create table tenant1.tableA(....`

Comment: Thank you @Igor for the suggestion. We would like to limit the changes we're making to just the table partition level. But if all else fail, we may consider employing this approach.

Comment: The thing is the clean up service is only one the many features that we have and is the only one that faces this dilemma with partitions. If we go with the isolated schema route, it would be involve a major change in the ecosystem.

Comment: @user7352353 I only asked which dbms because I didn't recognize the `ALTER TABLE .. PARTITION BY RANGE` syntax as valid for SQL Server

Comment: For Oracle it may make a difference what version. [this](https://www.databasejournal.com/features/oracle/partition-limits-in-oracle.html) states that for 11g, max partition count per table is about a million.

Comment: In SQL Server, max is 15000. In mySQL it's 8192. So yeah, if you need to support all three dbms, a straightforward scheme with 10000s of tenants is not going to work.

Comment: Thank you @RossPresser, yeah - seems like we'd need to look for other ways to do it instead of relying on partitions or come up with a different approach on the way we're using partitions.